# Decidability for an infinite sequence of decidable propositions

Tags: agda

I've been trying to prove this in Agda:

```
lemma : (P : ℕ → Set)
  → ((n : ℕ) → Dec (P n))
  → Dec (Σ[ n ∈ ℕ ] ¬ (P n))
```

In words:  We have an infinite sequence of decidable propositions.  Can we conclude that either a) all the propositions are true or b) you can find a counterexample?

I'm 70% sure this is not a conclusion you can draw without some extra axiom.  Is there a name for this, or some papers I can read?  If you need an extra axiom, what's a good one to go with?

(I came to this after working for a bit on Konig's Lemma, which I also suspect can't be proven without some additional assumptions.)

Comment: This is called a limited omniscience principle. In particular, it is the LPO on the natural numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is equivalent to solving the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) (perhaps relativized to an oracle), so this is a very strong assumption.

Fix a Turing machine M, suppose `P n` is the statement that M does not halt after being run `n` steps. This is decidable by simply running the machine. However, `Σ[ n ∈ ℕ ] ¬ (P n))` asks whether it is possible to find an `n` such that M halts in `n` steps. That is undecidable for a general Turing machine M.

As a general principle, being able to solve the Halting Problem relative to any oracle, is equivalent to the [Limited Principle of Omniscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_principle_of_omniscience) (LPO) as mentioned by Trebor. König's Lemma (KL) for general finitely branching trees is known to be equivalent to this, provided one has an enumeration of the nodes. In the most general possible setting, one might first need a weak form of choice — namely, to choose one from each of a countably infinite sequence of nonempty finite sets — and then use LPO to prove the full form of König's Lemma.

However, the Weak König's Lemma (WKL), which is limited to trees of finite $0,1$-sequences is known to be strictly weaker. In fact, it is related to the Lesser Limited Principle of Omniscience (LLPO) in the sense that for any infinite decidable tree T of finite $0,1$-sequences there is an infinite sequences of LLPO instances such that any simultaneous solution to all of these can be used to compute an infinite path through T.